# cuda kernel for column normalization (segmented reduction)

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm porting some code over to the GPU and I have it mostly implemented, except my algorithm needs to perform a column normalization step (or it should,  the algorithm works without it, but it would be better to normalize for algorithmic stability).

I am trying to think of the best way to implement this.  I already have a kernel that does reduction, so I could reuse that to get the column sums.  The number of columns could be as few as a few tens of columns that are a few thousand elements,  up to a few thousand columns with a few thousand elements each.  If I iteratively call my reduction kernel on each column I think the performance will be poor, so I am trying to think of better ways and am hoping someone else has already solved the problem in a more optimal way.

Comment: What you are looking for is called segmented scan or segmented reduction.

Comment: is there a good example of segmented scan/segmented reduction that you can recomend?  I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the open-source [CUDA Data-Parallel Primitives Library
(CUDPP)](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/) from the team at UC Davis/Nvidia.  It includes a fast segmented scan as well as parallel reductions.